# comparison of two pointer variable

Tags: c

I come across a program in C and see the pointer comparison program. What I didn't understand is these two statements.

```
j=&arr[4];
k=(arr+4);
```

the first statement is holding the address of the fifth element and the second statement syntax is what I saw first time. Can anybody explain me the second statement. and also 
after executing program j and k are equal. so they are pointing to the same location.

Answer (score 3):

> k=(arr+4);

means `k` will point to 4 elements ahead of `arr` location after it is decayed into a pointer to `index 0`.

array name decays to a pointer to it's zero index. by adding 4 means it'll point to 5th element.

[image]

Comment: Please don't say "where arr is pointing". `arr` is not a pointer, it is not pointing. The array name can be converted to a pointer to its first element however, in and of itself, it is not "pointing"

Comment: @Mike: Thanks. Pls. let me know if the terminologies are correct now?

Comment: +1 Better, thanks. Arrays being called pointers is a pet peeve of mine. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's the infamous pointer arithmetic! The statement simply assigns the address of the element at the address pointed to by `arr` and an offset of 4 elements to the right. `arr + 4` is pointing to the address of `arr[4]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply pointer arithmetic, mixed with C's indexing<->pointer defererence equivalence.

The former means that the expression `arr + 4` causes `arr` (the name of an array) to decay into simply a pointer to the array's first argument. In other words, `arr == &arr[0]` is true.

The latter is this equivalency, for any pointer a and integer i:

```
a[i] === *(a + i)
```

This means that the first expression, the assignment to `j`, can be read as `j = &(*(a + 4))`, which makes it (pretty) clear that it's just taking the address of the element with index 4, just as the `k` line is doing.

Comment: +1 good explanation as usual unwind. I'd +2 for mentioning the fact that `arr` *decays into a pointer* if I could

Answer (score 0):

This code uses a simple case of pointer arithmetics. It assigns the adress of the array ( +4 adresses, so it is the 5th element) to the pointer k.

Answer (score 0):

Every arr[4] statement is expending to (arr+4); statement by the compiler itself.

These two are equivalent and can be use interchangeably.

Answer (score -1):

Both are ways of getting a pointer value.

First `arr[x]` returns (x+1) array contents and you can get its address with & operator.
Second is known as pointer arithmetic and returns the address of the arr pointer plus x positions, so the x+1 address.

Comment: Please consider revising `address of the arr pointer`. `arr` is not a pointer, this is misleading.

Answer (score -1):

It's basic pointer arithmetic.  k is a pointer, arr is a pointer to the first element of the array (a pointer to arr[0]).  So by adding 4 to k, you move the pointer on 4 elements.  Therefore k=(arr+4) means k points to arr[4], which would be the fifth element, and the same as j.